# Experiencing an entity error related to a deleted drupal commerce product

Tags: entities, commerce

One of my clients has managed to disable, delete (he's not sure) one of his products because it was out of stock.  Issue is the title still appears in the product listing and when you click on the product it produces this error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_images. in
>   EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 335 of
>   /home3/***/public_html/client_sites/***.com/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

The product display is not listed in the backoffice (kickstart) but its dependent product variations (field images) are still active.

Cannot see anyway of fully removing this product, unless going into the database is required.

You help would be most grateful